# Set ion-scroll viewport height correctly

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

First thing first, here is the screenshot showing what I have implemented.

[image: app screenshot]

As you can see, there are 3 main parts - the header, the scrollable section and the tab bar. I managed to disable scrolling of `ion-content` with this:

```
ion-content.no-scroll {
    > .scroll-content {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

Right now I have set the height of the header to `24vh` and the `ion-scroll` element to `58vh`. I obtained these values by trial and error, which finally gives me an acceptable result as shown in the screenshot.

What I would like to ask is how to set the height of the `ion-scroll` element instead of hard-coding it relative to viewport height. I tried using `height: 100%`, but it just didn't work at all.

Below is the style I am using.

```
.header {
    height: 24vh;

    ion-scroll {
        height: 58vh;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Turns out my objective can be accomplished by making use of `ion-header` and `ion-content` as suggested by Sergey. Simply put the thumbnail, user name, and `ion-segment` inside `ion-header`, and the list of items in `ion-content` as usual will result in what I want.

If, for any reason, you cannot use `ion-header` to hold these contents, you may refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it working with `flex` and got rid of those hard-coded `height` properties.

Add a root container to wrap everything reside under `ion-content`.

```
.root-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<ion-content>
    <!-- extra container holding all contents -->
    <div class="root-container">
        <!-- fixed-height header -->
        <div class="header">...</div>

        <!-- built in Ionic 3 segment buttons -->
        <ion-segment>...</ion-segment>

        <!-- wrap ion-scroll up -->
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <ion-scroll>...</ion-scroll>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Then, I set a fixed height for the header.

```
.header {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Stop `ion-segment` from growing or shrinking.

```
ion-segment {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Most importantly, add a container to wrap `ion-scroll` up.

```
.scroll-container {
    flex: 1 1 100%;

    ion-scroll {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe why you had to deal with the header within ion-content and not through combination if ion-header and ion-content? Trying to understand what was so unique in your case that you couldnt use standard pattern

Comment: @SergeyRudenko To clarify, my `header` is not the `ion-header` element. It is just a `div` which functions as the "header section" in this page.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Doesn't it only work with `ion-navbar` and `ion-toolbar` as described in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Header/)?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks, just tried your solution. It is much simpler and should be the correct way of implementing it. Could you post an answer?

Comment: Hey happy to help, i dont have access to my pc. But let me know if you have more q. And yes you can use a lot more inside headers/footers

Comment: I'm trying to do same layout. I used `ion-toolbar` inside `ion-header` as @SergeyRudenko suggested and it worked painless.